# Allow logins with different IDs on the same machine with RAILS 4 and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

What I am trying to achieve is for a person with two differents login/passwords combinations to be able to login simultaneously into their 2 different accounts on a unique rails 4 app using devise.

What happens now is that when the person logs in with the first account all is good, but when the user then opens a new browser he has to logout before he can login again. When he logouts and logins again in the new window, the previous session  (in the old window) is also changed to the new login/password combo. As such it is not possible to run two different sessions on the same machine, as login in the new browser, logs out the old one.
It seems the root of the issue is that "logout" logouts all windows for the current user, rather than just the current window.

Any idea how achieving two parallel sessions with separate credentials on the same machine would be possible?

Comment: Trying using different browsers? (e.g., Firefox  and Chrome)

Comment: @jvillian that actually works. I was looking for a less hacky solution, programmatic solution, but thanks a lot still.